# BeautifulSoup parsing in Parallel

Tags: asynchronous, parallel-processing, beautifulsoup

I have a list of files I want to parse with BeautifulSoup. Running

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(file, 'html.parser')
```

takes about 2 seconds for each file so that

```
soups = []
for f in files:
    soups.append(BeautifulSoup(f, 'html.parser'))
```

takes about 40 seconds.
I'd like to run the `BeautifulSoup(file, 'html.parser')` on each file together so that the entire process finishes in about 2 seconds. Is this possible?

I've tried the following which didn't work:

```
async def parse_coroutine(F):
    return BeautifulSoup(F, 'html.parser')

async def parse(F):
    p = await parse_coroutine(F)
    return p

lst = [parse(f) for f in files]

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(*lst)

asyncio.run(main())
```

1) `BeautifulSoup(F, 'html.parser')` runs to completion and I cannot call other functions while its running

2) The code above doesn't give me what I want: I want the objects returned by `BeautifulSoup(F, 'html.parser')` to be stored in a list

According to [this](https://realpython.com/async-io-python/#the-asyncio-package-and-asyncawait), async doesn't really implement parallel processing the way I want it to. So what are my options? I'd like a concrete solution if possible because I'm not familiar with multithreading/concurrent programming etc.

Comment: Have you tried using gevent or normal threads